# send email using gmail smtp c#

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending email in .NET through Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

hello,

Im using code like below but I get an error:

```
"Unable to connect to the remote server"

 MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add("test1@gmail.com");
        mail.From = new MailAddress("test2@gmail.com");
        mail.Subject = "Test Email";
        string Body = "<b>Welcome to CodeDigest.Com!!</b>";
        mail.Body = Body;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("test1@gmail.com", "myPass");
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Send(mail);
```

Comment: The code looks good. There's a good chance your firewall is blocking outgoing requests on that port.

Comment: Try using port number 465 for SSL connection.

Answer (score 3):

You're not sending from the same email address you're authenticating with... You must add test1@gmail.com as the "from"

EDIT:As Bala R suggested, probably your firewall based on the error you get

Comment: @gruber probably the firewall